# Develop a faster algorithm for computing all possible subsets in R

Tags: r, algorithm

Suppose I have a categorical vector, and I want to write a function to get all the possible subsets of the categories, so I can re-categorise the vector.

Take a vector with 4 different categories (1 | 2 | 3 | 4) as an example, if I were to apply the function to it, it should generate 15 subsets with various number of new categories (in the below `|` separates new categories, while `,` separates old categories within a new category):

- 1 new category:   (1, 2, 3, 4)
- 2 new categories: (1 | 2, 3, 4)
- 2 new categories: (2 | 1, 3, 4)
- 2 new categories: (3 | 1, 2, 4)
- 2 new categories: (4 | 1, 2, 3)
- 2 new categories: (1, 2 | 3, 4)
- 2 new categories: (1, 3 | 2, 4)
- 2 new categories: (1, 4 | 2, 3)
- 3 new categories: (1 | 2 | 3, 4)
- 3 new categories: (1 | 3 | 2, 4)
- 3 new categories: (1 | 4 | 2, 3)
- 3 new categories: (2 | 3 | 1, 4)
- 3 new categories: (2 | 4 | 1, 3)
- 3 new categories: (3 | 4 | 1, 2)
- 4 new categories: (1 | 2 | 3 | 4)

I managed to write a function that can accomplish the job (**note: this function doesn't work directly on the categries from `vec`, instead, it generates and works on the index of the categories. The returned object `combins` is a nested list, whose length equals the number of possible combinations, and each element of `combins` is a list that contains the grouped indexes of old categories, each group is represented by an integer vector.**):

```
choose_cat <- function(vec) {
  cats <- unique(vec[!is.na(vec)]) # categories of the vector excluding NA
  num_cat <- length(cats) # number of categories
  splits <- unlist(lapply(seq_len(num_cat), function(x) { # split the categories into all possible pieces of various lengths
    combn(num_cat, x, simplify = F)
  }), recursive = F)
  combins <- lapply(seq_len(num_cat), function(y) { # choose from the pieces to constitute new combinations
    combn(splits, y, function(z) {
      set <- unlist(z)
      if ((!any(duplicated(set))) & (setequal(set, cats))) { # remove invalid combinations (those with duplicated categories or those missing any categories)
        z
      } else {
        NULL
      }
    }, simplify = F)
  })
  combins <- unlist(combins, recursive = F)
  combins <- combins[!vapply(combins, is.null, logical(1))]
  combins
}
```

It works fine when the number of categories is under 4, but when the number gets bigger than that, it gets really slow:

```
> system.time(choose_cat(1:4))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.03    0.00    0.03 

> system.time(choose_cat(1:5))
   user  system elapsed 
  53.94    0.00   53.93
```

I've tried to use `parLapply()` from the `parallel` package to substitute the second `lapply()` call in the function, but it got worse.

Does anyone have a more efficient algorithm and its implementation in R that can speed up the process?

Comment: Any reason why `4,3,2,1` for example is missing? Shouldn't there be 24 permutations of `1,2,3,4`? There are packages for this sort of thing, like `combinat`, with its `permn` function.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to get all possible subsets of a set of levels. This is O(2^N), so any algorithm you come up with is going to be impractical for even moderately-sized N. What are you _really_ trying to do?

Comment: @thelatemail, I want the subsets, so the order of the elements doesn't matter.

Comment: @HongOoi, I was trying to figure out how many possible variants can be derived from a given categorical variable if no other rules are applied, and I want the results for analyse. Any idea that can optimise the function to accept a variable with maybe up to 8 or 10 categories and execute within a reasonable amount of time (say 8 or 10 minutes)?